# trigger winforms program to run whenever a record is inserted in SQL Server via web app

Tags: c#, sql-server, triggers

I need to trigger a Winforms program that runs in taskbar tray whenever a row is added in SQL Server database from a web app. Is there a way to do this?

At the moment, the program runs all the time checking the database for new record and sleeps the underlying thread if nothing is inserted, but I need also to be able to trigger the program to run whenever a user inserted a row from a web app front-end.

**added**: web app, database, and winforms are running on the same one server.

thanks

Comment: This sounds like an incredibly bad design (sorry to put it so bluntly). You generally assume that SQL server and/or web servers are going to be running on a machine where there's possibly *no* user logged in at any particular time (and hence no desktop/system tray). If you actually need an external application (I'm not able to tell from your description), you'd be better building either a windows service or a console application that can run from a scheduled task.

Comment: That previous comment was quite negative, so I'll try to be more positive in this one. Can you describe what this current winforms program does? What sort of interaction does it have with the database and other systems?

Comment: ok, if I have windows service or a console app, how do I trigger it to run (outside schedule) when a user is inserting a record from a web app front-end? isn't winforms is external app in this context and can also run from a schedule task? anyway that's not my question.

Comment: Use a Windows Service and `SqlDependency` for the change notification.

Comment: Can you explain your set up? I'm assuming the database server is on a different box (probably hosted at an ISP somewhere), while it looks like your win forms app is running on user's machines. Is that correct. If so, can you use any TCP port or is your database server behind a firewall that you can configure (open additional ports). Also, is your web application server and database server on the same box? Are you familiar with using Sockets or WebClient on .NET?

Comment: "The program needs to get records and do what it needs to do to them from a certain table." - that could describe practically every program written that interacts with a database. I think most people would be thinking about eliminating the winforms app entirely, but it's difficult to know what to suggest with such a vague description.

Comment: @damien my question is very simple, you don't need to go round and round trying to complicate things up. if you run out of suggestion that means you are not capable of answering the question.

Answer (score 2):

"Standard" ways of triggering additional actions from inserts in SQL Server:

If the additional action is local to the database, and entirely implementable in transact SQL, the recommendation would be just to write it in [a trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).

If the additional action isn't implementable in transact SQL, then you might consider writing a CLR trigger. However, again I'd say that this is only appropriate if whatever is going to happen is local to the database.

If the additional action is appropriate to the server, but relies on e.g. other databases, or other features outside of the server, then you'd generally want to decouple the additional actions from the original `INSERT` operation. Two ways of dealing with this are SqlDependency, as others have said, or [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx).

If you're going the route of SqlDependency, you need something running permanently to use this object. This is what you'd typically put inside a windows service.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx).
Also check this link [Query Notifications in SQL Server (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you can refactor your application a bit, you could potentially create a duplex wcf service contract. here is a tutorial on that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731184.aspx
This is one of the message patterns available in WCF. You can use it to for doing things like firing events from the server, which the clients can subscribe to, which i think might be able to use.